# Can't connect to SQLSERVER 2008 R2 EXPRESS

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection, user-accounts

I'm in `SQLSERVER (2008 R2 EXPRESS)` administrators list. I'm in administrator role on my machine. And I can manually connect to SQLSERVER (via `Management Tools`) using ServerName (in my case it's `S-PROG-T\SQLEXPRESS`). During installation I decided to use only `Windows Authentication` mode. I can't connect to SS.

**Error message is:** `Login failed for user S-PROG-T\admin. Cannot open database 'ProjectDB' requested by the login.`

I'm using the following configuration for `NHibernate`:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">
        NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
        NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        NHibernate.Driver.Sql2008ClientDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
        Data Source=S-PROG-T\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectDB;Integrated Security=SSPI
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">
        true
    </property>
    <mapping resource="Project.Domain.Model.Entities.Mappings.Vehicle.hbm.xml" assembly="Project.Domain" />
 </session-factory>
```

And I've tried to connect using `.\SQLEXPRESS` data source. Inbound rules don't restrict SSMS.

What's wrong?
Thanks!

**EDIT: Unit tests**

Everything (`nhibernate` configuration, and schema export trial) starts inside my unit test (I don't know if this matters).

```
[TestFixture]
public class VehicleFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void TestSchemaExport()
    {
        new SchemaExport(new Configuration().Configure()).Execute(false, true, false);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Log information**

I discovered the next information inside a log (path: `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\`):

`Error: 18456; State: 38.`

`Login failed for user ‘S-PROG-T\Admin’.`

`Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.`

According to the article: http://sql-articles.com/articles/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-login-failed-error-18456/ database doesn’t exist or login doesn’t have access to the database.

I'm totally confused. Should I have created the database (manually) before I tried to export schema (sorry if the question is silly)?

**EDIT: Using Mixed Authentication mode**

I've set Mixed mode Authentication and created new login with `serveradmin` & `sysadmin` roles. But still the error message is the same, except for user name. Again I can manually do the same thing (connect and create db) with the login and its password.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Why are there two spaces in "Integrated  Security"?

Comment: @WernerHenze that's not the culprit. The typo exists only here.

Comment: Does it work when you omit the Initial Catalog? (-> Issue when connecting to the server or issue when opening the database?) Are you using Win7? If yes, are you running the Management Tools and your own program "as administrator"?

Comment: Can you connect with Windows Authentication mode with  the Manager tool? You say that you are admin on your machine, but what about where you install the database?

Comment: Yes I can connect in WA mode using Manager tool. And I don't clearly understand your second question, could you please explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I misunderstood the whole process. Everything's ok with Authentication and rather with connection strings. I just thought that schema export stands for database automated-creation  and then schema export. So I created a DB and successfully exported a schema.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect with NHibernate if you change database to 'master'?

Is ProjectDB database user S-PROG-T\admin mapped to server login that you use to connect using management tools?

Can you connect to database using user/password combination in property name="connection.connection_string" instead of integrated security = SSPI?

**EDIT** You write that you created new login. But still - **login** is something used for **SERVER** authentication. You must have database **user** in ProjectDB mapped to server login to access the database.

Look at this thread: [TSQL to Map User to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775234/tsql-to-map-user-to-database)

or read here: http://www.nerdymusings.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=41

Answer (score -1):

The website will not be using the same identity, therefore will not be an administrator. You can either define a specific identity and set your ApplicationPool (or your own admin account) to use this. Alternatively, use a login/password rather than integrated security.

Comment: Looks like he cannot even get in as his specific identity