# SQLServer Access restrictions between databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a view in DB1 to select data from tables in DB2.
Say "Create view DB1.A as Select * from DB2.B".

An user 'usr1' who has access only to DB1 is not able to select data from this view now. Getting the following error:
The server principal "usr1" is not able to access the database "DB2" under the current security context.

I know that such scenarios can be handled by granting read only access for DB1 to DB2 with 'With Grant' option in Teradata. Is there a similar option in SQL Server??

Comment: Is there some reason you can't simply add the user to "DB2" and only grant `select` permissions?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the following link to map your username to DB2 dataabase [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259605%28SQL.80%29.aspx) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775234/tsql-to-map-user-to-database)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, the only time this will work by default is if you meet two conditions...
1. The owner of the view is *also* the owner of the underlying table(s)
2. You have "cross database ownership chaining" activated

If you fail either of these conditions, you need to configure the security settings of the user/login that is querying the view, rather than just the owner of the view.

Neither Views nor Inline Table Valued Functions allow use of `EXECUTE AS OWNER` or similar options.

- [Ownership Chains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)