# SQL query to map login user to a particular database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I want to map login user (i.e. `TestUser`) to already created database (i.e. `JIRADB`), but after executing below query no user is added in `JIRADB`. 
Refer the image link provided, I want JIRADB to be checked after execution of the query.
Can someone help me with the exact query to achieve this task?

Here is the code, which I currently tried:-

```
USE [JIRADB]
GO
CREATE LOGIN TestUser WITH PASSWORD="sauser123', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[JIRADB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean "no user is added in JIRADB" or "I want JIRADB to be checked"? That the user isn't added to JIRA's user table (or whatever it's called) or that you want the new user login to use JIRADB as the default database? BTW you *can't* create an account named `sa`. That's the predefined administrator account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL to Map User to Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775234/tsql-to-map-user-to-database)

Comment: I just need a login user to be mapped with database.
For example :- I have created one login user as TestUser  and now i want to map it with a particular database in my case it is JIRADB or anyother database ABC.

Comment: Login and user are not equal. Maybe you should use: `CREATE USER TestUser  FROM LOGIN TestUser`

Answer (score 1):

Just creating a login isn't enough, that login needs a user in the database as well that is mapped to the login.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN TestUser WITH PASSWORD="sauser123', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[JIRADB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
USE [JIRADB]
GO
CREATE USER [TestUser] FOR LOGIN [TestUser]
GO
--Optional, add the user to database roles if required
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [TestUser]
GO
```

You will notice I also have an alter role statement in there as well, as if you just create a user in a database, it will just be a member of the public role, if you need any other permissions you must either add the user to a database role, or explicitly assign permissions to them.