# get [Create Login] script for existing logins before dropping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am doing a login clean-up activity in my SQL Server. The logins those are not required will be removed from the server. But, before deleting the logins, I want to keep the backup of the current logins (to revert back, by running "Create Login.." script for particular login).

When I `right click on Login > Script Login as > Create to` ..

It gives:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'ö©3ÚZ90T¥[³(1ëI¥6îõÛLáÚ', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
```

Here, the **user mapping is missing**. And this is manual process.

How can I get the actual script (with user mapping) for all the logins and specific logins? (I tried to search over Internet, getting for list of logins and their corresponding user mapping - not the script).

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1e45f0b-e050-466f-a66f-33bc41bd969e/how-to-script-out-the-user-mappings-for-the-loginsusers?forum=transactsql) MSDN post, you can fetch the user mappings with a query like:

```
    SELECT 
        susers.name AS ServerLogin,
        users.name  AS DBUser,
        DB_NAME()   AS [Database],              
        roles.name  AS DatabaseRoleMembership
    FROM       sys.database_principals   users
    INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members link   ON link.member_principal_id = users.principal_id
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals   roles  ON roles.principal_id       = link.role_principal_id
    INNER JOIN sys.server_principals     susers ON susers.[sid]             = users.[sid]
```

If you need to run this over multiple databases, I would use a cursor to run through each database in turn (building a dynamic SQL statement for each) and add the result for each database into a temp table before returning the complete set.

You already know how to structure the CREATE LOGIN command to create the server level login, so you just need to be able to create scripts to create the database level users and map the logins to those users.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775234/tsql-to-map-user-to-database) you can create users on a specific database with:

```
    USE <dbname>;
    CREATE USER <username> FROM LOGIN <loginname>;
```

and make a user a member of a specific group with:

```
   USE <dbname>
   EXEC sp_addrolemember '<dbrole>', '<username>';
```

Using the above, you could create a script to generate the necessary statements to recreate the logins and their mapped users at a later date.

For what it's worth, here's how I would do it:

```
    -- Generate statements to re-create server level logins
    SELECT  'IF(SUSER_ID(' + QUOTENAME(susers.name,'''') + ') IS NULL)' + 
    'BEGIN ' +
        'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(susers.name) + CASE WHEN susers.type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN'
                                                        THEN ' WITH PASSWORD = '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),logins.password_hash,1)+' HASHED'
                                                        ELSE ' FROM WINDOWS'
                                                   END + ';' + 
    'END;' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS LoginCreationStatements
    FROM      sys.server_principals AS susers
    LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins        AS logins ON susers.principal_id = susers.principal_id
    WHERE susers.type_desc IN ('SQL_LOGIN','WINDOWS_GROUP','WINDOWS_LOGIN')
      AND susers.name NOT LIKE '##%##' -- Ignore Microsoft shipped logins
      AND susers.name <> 'SA'

    -- Generate statements to re-create database level users and their role memberships
    DECLARE @dbName    NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @dbID      INT
    DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

    CREATE TABLE #userRoles
    (
        ServerLogin            NVARCHAR(128),
        DBUser                 NVARCHAR(128),
        [Database]             NVARCHAR(128),
        DatabaseId             INT,
        DatabaseRoleMembership NVARCHAR(128)
    )

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT database_id, name
        FROM sys.databases

    OPEN db_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
    INTO @dbID, @dbName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @statement = N'INSERT INTO #userRoles ' +
                          'SELECT ' +
                              'susers.name AS ServerLogin,' +
                              'users.name  AS DBUser,' +
                              QUOTENAME(@dbName,'''') + ' AS [Database],' +
                              QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@dbID),'''') + ' AS DatabaseId,' +
                              'roles.name   AS DatabaseRoleMembership ' +
                          'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '.sys.database_principals users ' +
                          'INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '.sys.database_role_members link ON link.member_principal_id = users.principal_id ' +
                          'INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '. sys.database_principals roles ON roles.principal_id = link.role_principal_id ' +
                          'INNER JOIN sys.server_principals susers ON susers.[sid] = users.[sid] ' +
                          'WHERE susers.type_desc IN (''SQL_LOGIN'',''WINDOWS_GROUP'',''WINDOWS_LOGIN'') ' +
                            'AND susers.name NOT LIKE ''##%##'' ' +
                            'AND susers.name <> ''SA'''

        EXEC sp_executesql @statement

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
        INTO @dbID, @dbName

    END

    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor

    -- Return the statements for re-creating database level users
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [' + [Database] + '].sys.database_principals WHERE name = ' + QUOTENAME(DBUser,'''') + ') ' +
            'BEGIN ' +
            'CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(DBUser) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(ServerLogin) + ' ' +
            'END;' AS UserCreationStatements
    FROM #userRoles

    -- Return the statements for re-creating role mappigns for database level users
    SELECT  'USE ' + QUOTENAME([Database]) + '; ' +
            'EXEC sp_addrolemember ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseRoleMembership) + ', ' + QUOTENAME(DBUser) + ';' AS UserRoleMappingStatements
    FROM #userRoles

    DROP TABLE #userRoles
```

This give 3 result sets - the first contains the statements to re-create the server level login, the second has the statements to re-create the database level users and the final one is the statements to re-map the logins to the users.

There are probably some things I've missed (like we should probably check that a target database still exists before running the CREATE USER statements and maybe you want to ignore certain databases like master and MSDB), but I hope that's helpful! :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that I've edited my answer to include a full example of how I would solve the problem posed in this question, just in case @pkawar already saw my original answer and it was not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Will take sometime to check and verify.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps. If it does resolve your question, please mark the answer as accepted. Have a great day!

Comment: Did you have a chance to check my answer [pkawar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1396986/pkawar)?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I built from pieces of scripts I have stolen over the years. I would love to give everyone appropriate credit but I don't know all the sources. It could use some streamlining but it seems to work for me.

```
CREATE TABLE #ToDo
(
 RID TINYINT
,MyLogin varchar(128)
,MyScript varchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE #MyTemp
(
 RID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key
,LoginName nvarchar(max)
,DBname nvarchar(max)
,Username nvarchar(max)
,AliasName nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #MyTemp
(LoginName,DBname,Username,AliasName)
EXEC master..sp_msloginmappings 

CREATE TABLE #Logins
(
 RID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key
,LoginName nvarchar(max)
,DBname nvarchar(max)
,Username nvarchar(max)
,AliasName nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #Logins
(LoginName,DBname,Username,AliasName)
SELECT LoginName,DBname,Username,AliasName
    FROM #MyTemp 
    WHERE dbname IS NOT NULL
    AND SUBSTRING(LoginName,1,1) != '#'
    AND SUBSTRING(LoginName,1,3) != 'NT '

CREATE TABLE #Alters
(
 RID INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key
,LoginName nvarchar(max)
,ALTERED nvarchar(max)
)

DECLARE @CurRow INT = 1
DECLARE @MaxRow INT
DECLARE @LoginName varchar(128)
DECLARE @DBName varchar(256)
DECLARE @MySQL varchar(max)

SELECT @MaxRow = MAX(RID)
    FROM #Logins

WHILE @CurRow <= @MaxRow
    BEGIN
        SELECT @LoginName = LoginName
            ,@DBName = DBName
            FROM #Logins
            WHERE RID = @CurRow

        ;WITH MyCTE
        AS
        (
        SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName
            , isnull (DP2.name, 'No members') AS DatabaseUserName   
            FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM  
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1  
                    ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id  
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2  
                    ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id  
            WHERE DP1.type = 'R'
            AND DP2.name Like @LoginName
        )
        INSERT INTO #Alters
        (LoginName,ALTERED)
        SELECT @LoginName, 'USE '+@DBName+';'+char(10)+char(13)+'GO;'+char(10)+char(13)+ 'EXEC sp_addrolemember '''+DatabaseRoleName+''', '''+@LoginName+''';'
            FROM MyCTE

        SET @CurRow = @CurRow + 1
    END

INSERT INTO #ToDo
(RID, MyLogin, MyScript)

SELECT RID = 0, MyLogin = REPLACE(REPLACE(QUOTENAME(SP.name), '[',''),']','')
    ,'IF (SUSER_ID('+QUOTENAME(SP.name,'''')+') IS NULL) BEGIN CREATE LOGIN ' +QUOTENAME(SP.name)
        +CASE WHEN SP.type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN' THEN ' WITH PASSWORD = ' +CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),SL.password_hash,1)
            + ' HASHED, CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' 
        +CASE WHEN SL.is_expiration_checked = 1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END +', CHECK_POLICY = ' 
        +CASE WHEN SL.is_policy_checked = 1 THEN 'ON,' ELSE 'OFF,' END ELSE ' FROM WINDOWS WITH' END 
        +' DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' +SP.default_database_name+ '], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[' +SP.default_language_name+ '] END;' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS MyScript
    FROM sys.server_principals AS SP
        LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins AS SL
            ON SP.principal_id = SL.principal_id
    WHERE SP.type IN ('S','G','U')
    AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
    AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
    AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
    AND SP.name <> ('sa');


INSERT INTO #ToDo
(RID, MyLogin, MyScript)
SELECT RID = 2
    , MyLogin = SL.name 
    ,'EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N''' + SL.name + ''', @rolename = N''' + SR.name + '''' AS MyScript
    FROM master.sys.server_role_members SRM
        JOIN master.sys.server_principals SR
            ON SR.principal_id = SRM.role_principal_id
        JOIN master.sys.server_principals SL
            ON SL.principal_id = SRM.member_principal_id
    WHERE SL.type IN ('S','G','U')
    AND SL.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
    AND SL.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
    AND SL.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
    AND SL.name <> ('sa');


INSERT INTO #ToDo
(RID, MyLogin, MyScript)
SELECT RID = 3
    ,MyLogin = SP.name 
    ,CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' THEN SrvPerm.state_desc ELSE 'GRANT' END
        + ' ' + SrvPerm.permission_name + ' TO [' + SP.name + ']' 
    + CASE WHEN SrvPerm.state_desc <> 'GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION' THEN '' ELSE ' WITH GRANT OPTION' END collate database_default AS MyScript
    FROM sys.server_permissions AS SrvPerm 
        JOIN sys.server_principals AS SP
            ON SrvPerm.grantee_principal_id = SP.principal_id 
    WHERE   SP.type IN ( 'S', 'U', 'G' ) 
            AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
            AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
            AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
            AND SP.name <> ('sa');

INSERT INTO #ToDo
(RID, MyLogin, MyScript)
SELECT RID = 4, MyLogin = LoginName, MyScript = ALTERED
    FROM #Alters
    ORDER BY LoginName, ALTERED

--SELECT * FROM #ToDo

SELECT RID, MyLogin, MyScript
    FROM #ToDo
    ORDER BY MyLogin, RID, MyScript

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE #MyTemp
DROP TABLE #Logins
DROP TABLE #Alters
DROP TABLE #ToDo
```